# Synchronize ReverseGeocodeQuery handlers in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone, reverse-geocoding

I have question. I've got one ReverseGeocodeQuery which'll provide me details about my GPS location. Now I want to synchronize few ReverseGeocodeQuerys (each one for other GPS location). But when I just start all Query in one moment they won't execute...

Is there simple way to synchronize that Querys?

```
for(int i = 0; i<mySimulation.Count(); i++)
                {

                    if (i==0)
                    {
                        AddMapLayer(mySimulation.ElementAt(i).Coordinate, Colors.Yellow, false);

                        myReverseGeocodeQuery_1 = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
                        myReverseGeocodeQuery_1.GeoCoordinate = mySimulation.ElementAt(i).Coordinate;
                        myReverseGeocodeQuery_1.QueryCompleted += ReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted_1;
                        myReverseGeocodeQuery_1.QueryAsync();
                    }

                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        AddMapLayer(mySimulation.ElementAt(i).Coordinate, Colors.Orange, false);

                        myReverseGeocodeQuery_2 = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
                        myReverseGeocodeQuery_2.GeoCoordinate = mySimulation.ElementAt(i).Coordinate;
                        myReverseGeocodeQuery_2.QueryCompleted += ReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted_2;
                        myReverseGeocodeQuery_2.QueryAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an **[AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx)**:

```
AutoResetEvent done = new AutoResetEvent(true);
...
for(int i = 0; i<mySimulation.Count(); i++)
{
    // Is somebody working?
    // If so I wait...
    done.WaitOne();

    if (i==0)
    {
        ....
        myReverseGeocodeQuery_1.QueryCompleted += ReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted_1;
        done.Reset(); // Hey I'm working, wait!
        myReverseGeocodeQuery_1.QueryAsync();
    }
    ...
}
...
void ReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted_1(...)
{
    ...
    done.Set(); // I'm done! Your turn...
}
```

The main thread *should* (*should* and not *will* because of the late hour) be blocked on *WaitOne* while any of the geo query is running, avoiding that another be started at the same time...

Comment: It's not working. I debug code, and notice that:

It loop once. Second loop stops on done.WaitOne(); and stuck here. Maybe we shouldn't use Reset in AutoResetEvent?

Comment: The main thread should wait until the first one has finished: "done.Set" is here to unblock the main thread. So could you check that done.Set is correctly invoked.

Comment: It looks like done.Set is not being invoked. I don't know why.

Comment: Are you sure the ReverseGeocodeQuery completes? Could you show the code with the AutoResetEvents please.